# All Urls redirect to home page in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website. It has a problem. All links there on the website are redirecting to the home page. I have checked the htaccess too but it seems perfect to me. Here is the htaccess code.

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ http://immigrationpoint.co.uk/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

The website is 
http://immigrationpoint.co.uk/

If you try to click any link, all it does is that redirects you to the home page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- switching to the Twenty Eleven theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.
- [resetting the plugins folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) by FTP or PhpMyAdmin. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.

Comment: if I change the theme it starts working. What does this mean?